# BAT file for robocopy with variables and spaces in source path issue

Tags: variables, concatenation, robocopy

I am looking to use Robocopy to copy out specific files from various network locations but I am having an issue figuring out how to combine an argument with a path that has a space. I asm having issues concatenating the source.

```
:: %1 MachineName
:: %2 Username

Robocopy \\%1\C$\Users\%2\AppData\Local\Google\Chrom\User Data\ C:\Temp\%2 /E
```

This fails as Robocopy see destination as Data\

What is the best way to concatenate the source path?

Comment: Have you tried just putting quotes around "user data"?  Or is the problem that there are spaces in %1/%2?